# Finding the particular solution that satifies the inital conditions

Tags: calculus

$y = C_1 + C_2 \ln (x)$ is a solution to $x y'' + y' = 0$.

The boundary conditions are $y = 0$ when $x = 9$ and $y' = \frac 19$ when $x = 9$.

I have no idea where to start this problem.

Answer (score 3):

$y=c_1+c_2lnx$
$y'=\frac{c_2}{x}$
$y''=\frac{-c_2}{x^2}$ Here I don't think we need to use the condition $xy''+y'=0$

$y'=\frac{c_2}{x}=\frac19$ when x=9, thus $c_2=1$
$y=c_1+ln(9)=0$, $c_1=-ln(9)$

Thus $y=-ln(9)+lnx$

Answer (score 0):

Since $y' (x) = \frac{C_2}{x}$, from the boundary condition $y ' (9) = \frac{1}{9}$, we conclude that $C_2 = 1$. Hence, $y (x) = C_1 + \ln (x)$. Using the boundary condition $y (9) = 0$, we conclude that $C_1 = - \ln (9)$. Thus,

$$y (x) = \ln (x) - \ln (9) = \ln \left(\frac{x}{9}\right)$$

Comment: thank you, i think this sorta makes sense now, although ill need more practice